# Usar ou não usar aspas na porção de código no título da pergunta e seu impacto em termos de SEO

Tags: debate, perguntas, título

Ao colocar a seguinte pergunta:

> [Tipo adequado para servir Javascript: “text/javascript” ou “application/x-javascript” ou “application/javascript”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42755/223)

Surgiu-me uma questão que se prende pelo alcance obtido via motores de busca.

Se usarmos aspas para delimitar uma porção de código, é a minha opinião que estamos a aumentar a leitura do título. Mas que impacto tem as aspas em termos de [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization)?

## Cenário

Uma pesquisa por:

```
text/javascript ou application/x-javascript
```

Vai efetivamente despoletar como resultado a pergunta em cima referenciada ou teremos que pesquisar:

```
“text/javascript” ou “application/x-javascript”
```

## Analise

Após analisar no Google, concluo que não parece fazer diferença alguma:

Uma pesquisa por: [text/javascript ou application/x-javascript ou application/javascript](https://www.google.pt/#q=text%2Fjavascript%20ou%20application%2Fx-javascript%20ou%20application%2Fjavascript)

[image: Captura de tela resultados Google]

E uma pesquisa por: [“text/javascript” ou “application/x-javascript” ou “application/javascript”](https://www.google.pt/#q=%E2%80%9Ctext%2Fjavascript%E2%80%9D+ou+%E2%80%9Capplication%2Fx-javascript%E2%80%9D+ou+%E2%80%9Capplication%2Fjavascript%E2%80%9D)

[image: Captura de tela resultados Google]

## Debate

É seguro assumir que as aspas não vão ter um impacto negativo em termos de [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) fazendo com que as perguntas do SOpt deixem de estar presentes nos primeiros resultados de qualquer motor de busca, podendo assim assumir-se que o código presente nos títulos das perguntas pode/deve ser delimitado por aspas ou plicas simples?

Comment: Normalmente as `"aspas"` são usadas para citação ou reprodução, e não como destaque de palavra para fins de SEO. Acredito que o uso seja um recurso do próprio mecanismo de busca para delimitar um a exatidão de um trecho que deseja encontrar.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Correto, em termos de escrita, o uso das aspas tem por conceito envolver uma citação, mas a minha questão relaciona-se com o fato de existir uma convenção de que nos títulos a porção de código ai existente deve estar delimitada para facilitar a leitura, sejam aspas ou plicas simples, e o fato desta convenção ter ou não impacto negativo em termos de SEO face ao que um utilizador normalmente escreve para procurar algo, onde acredito que 99.9% das pessoas não usa aspas num motor de busca :)

Comment: @PapaCharlie **Em suma**, a minha questão procura levantar uma discussão sobre o uso ou não de delimitadores para código que faça parte do título da pergunta com vista a não ter impacto negativo em termos de SEO com o objetivo de garantir que as perguntas do SOpt vão estar na primeira página de qualquer motor de busca (quando aplicável)!

Comment: As aspas não fazem parte das práticas negativas para alavancar resultados, não acredito que tenha impacto negativo. Acho 'elegante' a proposta das aspas.

Comment: Apesar de louvável, acho que normatizar algo assim para tentar beneficiar um sistema que talvez nenhum de nós (salvo alguém aqui que trabalhe no Google) sabe *exatamente* como funciona é provavelmente esforço jogado fora... Ninguém sabe como o PageRank funciona de verdade, e o Google vive mudando. Além disso, não acho que fariam diferença... Considerando-se que seja um algorítimo bem sofisticado

Comment: @Gabe "normatizar" é um bocado acima das minhas expetativas para o resultado do presente debate. Pretendia mais obter um _educated guess_: Um palpite baseado no conhecimento e experiência e, portanto, provável que seja correto. Irei oportunamente dar seguimento a alguns testes e responder com o resultado.